# Location Information length in the terminal reponse of PROVIDE LOCAL INFORMATION

Tags: javacard, apdu, sim-card, sim-toolkit

why the length of  Location Information is different? when I ask location info using PROVIDE LOCAL INFORMATION, the length of Location Information is 7 sometimes, and it is 9 sometimes. like this:

//Terminal Response

```
8014000015810301260002028281030106130764F01010D9286C; SW=910B
```

//Terminal Response

```
8014000017810301260002028281030106130964F010A05D3C49006D; SW=9000
```

can anyone tell me which spec to check?

Answer (score 3):

ETSI TS 102 223 defines the Provide Local Information components. It mentions that the location information portion will be "Access technology specific" in section 8.19.

If we look at 3GPP TS 31.111 we see again in section 8.19 that location information could have length "09", "07", "05", "00". The note describe under which circumstances the different lengths are found.

```
Note 1 
The Extended Cell Identity Value is not available in GERAN. When in GERAN, 
this field shall not be present and the length field shall be set to ‘07’.
```

I believe when you are executing the provide local information query, you could at times be in a GSM, EDGE, UMTS or LTE zones and for each access technology the information is different.

Kind Regards,